# Unsupported grant type when getting OAuth token for Reddit API

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0, reddit

I'm trying to get an OAuth token for the Reddit API following the [Application Only OAuth instructions](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#application-only-oauth).  My reddit app is an installed app, so for my `grant_type` I'm using `https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client`.

Currently I'm running a very short JS script to query the API and get a token:

```js
const APP_ID = 'MY_APP_ID'
const DEVICE_ID = 'TRACKING_ID_20_TO_30_CHARS'


let form = new FormData()
form.append('grant_type', 'https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client')
form.append('device_id', DEVICE_ID)

fetch('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: new Headers({
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`${APP_ID}:`)}`,
   }),
   body: form })
  .then(handleResponse)
  .then(function(data) {
console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))

function handleResponse(response) {
  return response.json()
}
```

(Note: running the snippet as-is will give you a NetworkError because the APP_ID isn't a real one and I don't want to give mine out.)

The response I get is:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

When I try the same API request using a REST client I get back the expected response, so this makes me think that the problem is JavaScript-related.  Since the `grant_type` matches what the instructions say I'm not really sure what to do with the error.  I'm hoping someone else more experienced with OAuth will know what is going on here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the use of the `FormData` object.  In earlier stages of troubleshooting I found [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/4tekpe/cannot_get_past_unsupported_grant_type_with_token/d5gqbh3/) on Reddit and decided to use it, but that didn't work for me.

It was submitting the data as `multipart/form-data` rather than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which Reddit's OAuth server did not like.  I wrote a helper function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751527/3225398) which did the trick:

```
function urlEncode(data) {
  let out = [];

  for (let key in data) {
    out.push(`${key}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key])}`);
  }

  return out.join('&')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a reddit bot years ago and today am porting it to Laravel and ran into the same "Unsupported grant type" and it was due to the encoding of the form data.

```
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'User-Agent'=>$this->bot_name
    ])->withBasicAuth($this->client_id,$this->client_secret)
        //LINE BELOW DIDN'T WORK
        //->bodyFormat('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        //ADDING THIS MADE IT WORK
        ->asForm()
        ->post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',[
            'grant_type'=>'password',
            'username'=>$this->username,
            'password'=>$this->password
        ]);
```