# How do I edit or updated an array of Objects CRUD app dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, oop, data-structures

I am working on a bookmark "collector" app that allows users save websites urls as a collection. I have created an array collectX in the localstorage to save each collections. However I am trying to edit and update each collections that have created on another HTML page.

How can I do that?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
//get form values 
// create an object of the form values
//create an empty array
//append object of the form values to the empty array
//display array object values

showCollection();

var getButton = document.getElementById('clickIt');
var collectionTitle = document.getElementById("title");
var collectionDescription = document.getElementById('describe')


getButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var collections = {
        title: collectionTitle.value,
        description: collectionDescription.value,
        collectedWebsites:[]
    }

    let webCollections = localStorage.getItem('collectx');
    if(webCollections == null){
        var collectionObj = []
        alert('storage is empty')
    }
    else{
        collectionObj = JSON.parse(webCollections);
    }
    collectionObj.push(collections);
    localStorage.setItem("collectx", JSON.stringify(collectionObj));
    showCollection()
});


function showCollection(){
    let webCollections =  localStorage.getItem('collectx')
    if(webCollections == null){
        var collectionObj = []
        alert('storage is empty')
    }
    else{
        collectionObj = JSON.parse(webCollections);
    }
    let html= ''
    var demos = document.getElementById('demo');
    collectionObj.forEach(function(item, index){
        html += `<div class="collects"> 
        Title: ${item.title} <br>
        Description: ${item.description} </div>`
      })
      demos.innerHTML = html
   
    
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #000;
}
.collects{
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CollectX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <form id="forms">
        <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Collection name">
        <br>
        <br>
         <input id="describe" type="text" placeholder="Description">
        <button id="clickIt"> Submit </button>
      </form>
      
     <div id="demo">

     </div>

    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3jgezwr/2/

P.S: I have tried to the method used on this page: https://www.xul.fr/javascript/parameters.php

Comment: You explained what you want to do, what you did so far (good!) but you didn't explain why that didn't work, if you got stuck, if you got an error, etc... be detailed in your problem.

Comment: I have edited my post. 
I would like to let users save website Urls in the  collectedWebsites Array in the collectX array stored when a user clicks on one of the collections created in the DOM. I have tried to get the collections using the index of the collection that the user clicked on but I couldnt get it to work.

Comment: What did not work? Share what you tried while debugging this.

Comment: Please share an example of the data in localStorage

Comment: I tried what I saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656168/javascript-array-to-urlencoded
I thought I would be able to render a new HTML page that has a form element, with the index of the collections in the localStorage.

Comment: @Mario here is it: 
var collectx= [
{"title":"aa","description":"This is all about LOSODE","collectedWebsites":[]},
{"title":"help","description":"I am drwoning","collectedWebsites":[]}
]

Comment: I don't understand, in the form where you save the information in localStorage you don't send any url,

Comment: I understand in `collectedWebsites` array should be urls, but how are these urls be collected because there is no field in the form

Comment: @Mario That is where I am stuck. That is what I was trying to achieve but I kinda got stuck. So I really don't know how to go about collecting the urls in the collectedWebsites array

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look to this example

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.collects {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="form">
  <div>
    <input name="title" placeholder="Title" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="describe" placeholder="Describe" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="links" placeholder="Add links separated by coma" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
const form = document.forms.form;

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

function getData() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("collectx")) ?? [];
}

function submitHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = event.target;
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  const currentData = getData();

  localStorage.setItem("collectx", JSON.stringify([...currentData, data]));

  form.reset();

  render();
}

function render() {
  const collection = getData();
  const entries = collection
    .map(
      ({ title, describe, links }) => `
        <div class="collects">
          <p>Title: ${title}</p>
          <p>Describe: ${describe}</p>
          <p>Links: ${links && links
            .split(",")
            .map((link) => `<a href="${link}">${link}</a>`)
            .join("<br />")}
          </p>
        </div>`
    )
    .join("");

  document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML = `
  <div>
    ${entries}
  </div>
`;
}

render();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3ws94zo/2/

The idea is to add a input to enter links separated by coma. In a real solution, you probably will need to validate the urls

Comment: Hi @mario let say I want to fill in the urls in another html page.  How do I go about that???